# How evaluate targeting users with using User Property On Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In case of my firebase has `paid` user property, values are `true` or `false` . Everyone is `false` first. If I use FCM, I need segment users with `NOT paid` user property, can I filter only `NOT paid` users as of this moment? Or is it meaning ALL users?

Comment: If all users have a value for the `paid` property, you should be able to select users that have `paid` set to `false`. Is that not working for you?

Comment: I concern anyone has `paid = false` event at the first opened. Can firebase evaluate targeting only `NOT paid` users at this moment? Or It mean ALL users because anyone has `paid = false` event at the first opened?